# How to show 30k Polylines on google map with DeckGL

Tags: angular, google-maps, deck.gl

I am using the angular Google Maps library. we have a use case where users can upload a huge list (around 30k) polylines on the Map. At the moment the Map gets freeze and nothing is working.

I decided to use Deckgl to render those big data but the problem is that. we also allow users to edit those polylines on the map. (Maybe I don't know how to use Deckgl here).

Comment: Please provide a codepen/codesandox showing your problem.

Comment: @AdriSolid I have implemented a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-breeze-11fd6?file=/src/index.js:113-128

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `GoogleMapsOverlay` from `@deck.gl/google-maps` then use deck.gl layers, not google-maps rendering logic.

In your `drawPolyline` function you can use, i.e, a `ScatterplotLayer`:

```
overlay.setProps({
  layers: [
    new ScatterplotLayer({
      data: polylines,
      opacity: 0.7,
      getPosition: d => d,
      radiusUnits: 'pixels',
      radiusMinPixels: 2,
    })
  ]
});
```

Comment: But I guess that will not draw a polyline. please correct me If I am wrong

Comment: Try to use a `LineLayer` instead https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/layers/line-layer